# macOS - addWindowController doesn't set WindowController's document property

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I am creating a window controller that I want to add to my Document object in the Document's makeWindowControllers function. However, after I have added this window controller, I can not resolve the windowController's Document object. This property should be set by my Document on the window controller in the addWindowController call. Any ideas as to why this might be the case?

```
let movieStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("MovieWindowStoryboard"), bundle: nil)
movieWindowController = movieStoryboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("MovieWindowController")) as? NSWindowController
self.addWindowController(movieWindowController)
movieWindowController.window?.performClose(self)
```

Comment: When do you access `document`? Do you call `performClose`in `makeWindowControllers`?

Comment: I access document after I open the window. I invite performClose to make the window hidden when the document opens. I removed it and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Where in code is "after I open the window"? Is `document` `nil` at the end of `makeWindowControllers`? I tried your code but it doesn't compile. Post a [mre] please.